# Should you use std::unique_ptr alongside std::function?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, unique-ptr, std-function

I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to deal with allocation and deallocation of `std::function`.

Of course the underlying function is never going to be deallocated, but the captured variables etc. need to be deallocated.

I presume that this is deallocated inside the destructor of `std::function`.

Does this mean the best way to manage functions that persist is through the use of `std::unique_ptr<std::function<...>>` and `std::shared_ptr<std::function<...>>`, or even just a raw pointer `std::function<...>*`?

Wouldn't this be an extra pointer of indirection? Is this the recommended way to go?

Comment: `std::function` manages the data it holds itself.  You shouldn't need to dynamically allocate one.  You shouldn't really need to manually dynamically allocate any standard library class type.

Comment: @NathanOliver Right, of course, that makes sense now that I think about it. Thanks

Comment: When you need to pass a std::function around, just copy it (Pass by value). The function itself does NOT capture any extra variables, that is what lambda functions are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that `std::function` is not a lambda. A `std::function` don't have captures. It's a polymorphic wrapper around a function like object like a lambda.

A (extremely rough and incomlete and incorrect) representation of `std::function` looks like this:

```
template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct function {
    function(auto lambda) :
        fptr{[](void* l, Args...){ static_cast<decltype(lambda)>(l)(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }}
        function_object{new auto(lambda)} {}
    
    auto operator()(Args...) const -> R {
        return fptr(function_object, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    // other members...

private:
    R(*fptr)(void*, Args...);
    void* function_object;
};
```

As you can see, the `function_object` member is dynamically allocated. This is the lambda, and the lambda contains the captures. They will only be deleted when the `std::function` destructor is called.

Then, also remember that `std::function` respects value semantics. This means that if the `std::function` is copied, the lambda held inside is also copied. This means you can freely copy, move around, make some copies out of scope, call the function and it won't affect other copies.

This means this code works:

```
auto make_function_with_captures(double a, double b) -> std::function<double()> {
    // captures 'a' and 'b' as values
    auto lambda = [a, b] {
        return a + b;
    };

    // Here, 'lambda' is copied in the std::function
    return std::function<double()>{lambda};
    
} // 'lambda' goes out of scope here, with its captures

int main() {
    auto function = make_function_with_captures(1.2, 4.5);

    // Here, use a copy of the lambda that was created in the function        
    double a = function();
}
```

> Wouldn't this be an extra pointer of indirection?

Yes. This would be two pointer indirection with a virtual call.

> Is this the recommended way to go?

I would answer this question to "no" most of the time, like 98% of cases.